Already have UTF-8 in vsc (python) but stdout makes strange characters
This stdout doesn't work in UTF-8 as my Visual Studio Code and my computer (chcp 850)

 Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS espec¡fico para la conexi¢n. . :
   Descripci¢n . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Direcci¢n f¡sica. . . . . . . . . . . . . : E0-C2-64-64-FA-92
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : s¡
   Configuraci¢n autom tica habilitada . . . : s¡


Code:
import subprocess

def ejecutar_comando(comando_Red):
    resultado = subprocess.run(comando_Red, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return resultado.stdout.strip('UTF-8')

comando_Red = [
    "ipconfig /all",
    "getmac"
]

for comando_Red in comando_Red :
    salida = ejecutar_comando(comando_Red)
    print (salida)

I was expecting an UTF-8 output with things like í, á, ó, ú....
my cmd and powershell work in chcp 850 and show proper Latin characters.

meanwhile, the OP will probably get his workaround by installing the windows-terminal app, and using cmd from within it.  The outputs are a clear example of the salad windows typically does with its two internal charmaps for output (the app thinks it should output latin1,and the terminal expects cp850 family codec, both non-multibyte)

You face a mojibake case: 'Direcci¢n f¡sica'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'cp850') returns 'Dirección física' and vice versa: 'Dirección física'.encode( 'cp850').decode( 'cp1252') -> 'Direcci¢n f¡sica'.

Thanks everyone, but still don't have a way to solve it, this mojibake case has no sense for me becasue my cmd and powershell have the characters à, ò, ì ...., tried the commands out there and they show normally.

Thanks everyone, I solved this by adding cp850 and changing the structure a little bit.
Asuming I just had kind of a mess at printing the output, then my cmd just went crazy.
import subprocess

# Execute the command and capture output
result = subprocess.run(['systeminfo'], capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='cp850')

# print output
print(result.stdout)


Your understanding of character encoding is clearly incomplete. If the console is configured for code page 850 then that's what you should tell Python, and expect from the output (and not, for example, UTF-8).
Assuming that the subprocess produces output in this encoding,
def ejecutar_comando(comando_Red):
    resultado = subprocess.run(
        comando_Red, capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='cp850')
    return resultado.stdout

The crucial addition is encoding='cp850' which tells Python how to decode the output from the subprocess.
.strip('UTF-8') would remove any occurrence of U, T, F, -, or 8 on either side of the string, but that's clearly not required or correct here.
>>> "fnord".strip("fd")
'nor'

Tangentially, I don't believe shell=True is necessary or useful here, so I removed that, too.
This still requires your Python to be configured to correctly encode output for the current code page. Please refer to Python, Unicode, and the Windows console for details about that.
More likely, your console is actually cp1252.
>>> "configuración".encode("cp850").decode("cp1252")
'configuraci¢n'

If you need help identifying encodings, I humbly offer you https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/
>>> "conciguración".encode("cp1252")
b'conciguraci\xa2n'

If you have \xa2 and want to check in which encodings that corresponds to ó, see https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#a2
Perhaps see also the Stack Overflow character-encoding tag info page

thank you, you almost got it, it was more or less like what you were saying.

Your own answer seems to exactly repeat the code from the first half of this one, with less  explanation. How is that "almost"?
